# Can I create and save a signature as default in Outlook through VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook, signature

I have made some progress and hence editing my description

I have a .xls file with signature that user save.
User clicks a custom button which opens a FileDialog from where he searches and selects the signature file. The code extracts the signature from the xls file and creates an HTML file in "AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Signatures". My code works uptill this part--it opens the file and extracts the signature portion, creates HTML, the signature option is visible in the Signature Menu in Outlook. But when i click the mode-generated signature option, it is not displayed in the mail body.

I compared it with a manually created Signature in Outlook and after comparing the 2 HTML files, I feel this portion is causing the problem.
[image]
The marked portion is in the manually created signature but not in my code generated one. My inference is I am not creating a signature type HTML file as such. Can anyone help me with this? And my initial question still remains how do I make my code generated signature the default one?

My Code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub MailSignatur2()

Dim SigFolder2 As String
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Dim selectedItem As Variant
Dim SigFolder As String
Dim ExcelFileName As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim Signature As String
Dim oMsg As MailItem
Dim c As Variant
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim DateFormat As String
Dim objSign As MailItem

SigFolder2 = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Downloads\"
Debug.Print SigFolder2


Set fd = objExcel.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
.Filters.Clear
 .InitialFileName = SigFolder2
 .AllowMultiSelect = False
 .Title = "Select Signature File"
End With



If fd.Show = -1 Then
    For Each selectedItem In fd.SelectedItems
        SigFolder = selectedItem
    Next
Else
Exit Sub
End If

ExcelFileName = SigFolder
FileName = Left(fso.GetFileName(ExcelFileName), InStr(fso.GetFileName(ExcelFileName), ".") - 1)

Debug.Print ExcelFileName
Debug.Print FileName
Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFileName)
Signature = vbNullString

For Each c In exWb.Sheets(FileName).Range("A1:A30")
    If c.Value = "$" Then
        Exit For
    Else
    If c.Value = "%" Then
    Signature = Signature & "<hr align='left' width='20%'><br>"
    Else
        Signature = Signature & c.Value & "<br>"
    End If
    End If
Next c

On Error Resume Next
Set oMsg = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
On Error GoTo 0

Set objSign = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With objSign
  .HTMLBody = "<html><body><div><p>" & Signature & "</p></div></body></html>"
End With

saveFolder = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\"
objSign.SaveAs saveFolder & "Official_Sign.html", olHTML

Debug.Print saveFolder
ExitRoutine:
    Set oMsg = Nothing
    Set exWb = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Very small mistake.It should be .htm instead of .html

```
objSign.SaveAs saveFolder & "Official_Sign.htm", olHTML
```